# Woman Discovers she was a Male Astronaut

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story where Happily Married woman discovers that she was a male astronaut on a Medical Ship and that her Husband is the Pilot. As I remember the Ship crashed during a war and She is drugged to feel that she has a happy life. One day the Drug (In the shape of an egg) is boiled, thus rendering it ineffective. Can't quite remember how the story ends except I recall her continuing to take the drug to remain happy whilst her "Husband" will live with the knowledge that they will never be rescued.

Answer (score 11):

Bob Shaw's "Call me Dumbo". A nasty piece of work! It ends with the line "And all she wanted was to be his wife."

Comment: You can read it [here](https://archive.org/stream/1966-12_IF#page/n95/mode/2up).